# Power Mock unit tests for Static methods of local scope

Tags: java, unit-testing, static-methods, powermock, powermockito

Is there a good way to use power mockito for mocking the static method shown below in the code?

```
@Singleton
public class AnimalWorks {

    public void verifyAnimal(Protocol proto, Set<Animal> successAnimals, Set<AnimalRule> rules, String zookeeper,OtherParams additionalParams) throws AnimalException, DAOException {
        ...

        // Static method call to fromAnimalId(arg1,arg2) below:
        // How to mock this method call with PowerMockito so I can have a custom aniSet?

        Set<Animal> aniSet = AnimalGenerator.fromAnimalId(dbtool, additionalParams); 

        ...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mocking static methods using PowerMock is explained [here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-powermock-mock-static) for example.

But please keep in mind: when talking about your **own** production code, then this is only the second best solution! Because: that **static** call is actually a *design* problem.

Yes, static methods are convenient, but they also lead to direct/tight coupling of your code. And of course, they break ordinary unit testing with EasyMock or Mockito ...

So, the alternative answer is: don't use PowerMock. Instead step back, and remove that **static** dependency from your code. For example by creating an interface that denotes the required functionality; and then instead of making that static call within your code, you use **dependency injection** to acquire some object implementing that interface.

And all of a sudden, you don't need PowerMock any more.

Final word of warning: many people use PowerMock without much problems. But when you do some research, you will also find a lot of people having all kinds of weird problems with PowerMock. So, don't just pick that tool because it seems more convenient. Understand that *improving* your design completely **kills** the need for using that tool!

EDIT:

The point is: you should **never** do things because somebody says "make it so". Ideally, you learn about pros and cons of the different approaches, and then you decide which way to turn; depending on that analysis. Of course, **static** was available in Java since the very first day; thus there are many people showing nice use cases for it.

But that doesn't change the downsides I mentioned (direct, tight coupling). Thing is: I completely **stopped** using **statics** - in ways that prevent from unit testing. And I never regretted that.

And you see, there are people that claim that **static** prevents you from creating *testable* code - like [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) (watching those videos is worth each minute!). It is not like I came up with that idea.

Comment: The issue is that is modeled as a static factory method as described in effective java. https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA5&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Agreed. choice of static method for this non-instantiable class is a design time decision that is hard to change now. Circling back to this problem- I looked at the dzone article, while it touches upon a lot of pieces for solving this puzzle I am still having a hard time to make it work for my example above and it would be really helpful if a test code snippet  be provided for the problem above.